# Displaying a textarea for job option in Rundeck

Tags: rundeck

How do I format my job option input as a multi line text input (textarea)?

I have done some research and found this pull request on the Rundeck project, but without any documentation I'm not sure this is what I am looking for.

I have tried the following in my job definition:

```
- description: Some description
  options:
  - name: Change me
    displayType: MULTI_LINE
  # Other properties...
```

I have also tried with `displayType` `multiline` but with no avail.

What is the correct way to use a textarea for a job in Rundeck?

Comment: Not an actual answer, but I hacked it by adding a custom JavaScript for every page in rundeck (through Apache), looking for an input field with a particular name, e.g. `something_`, knowing that if it ends with `_`, it means transform it into a textarea with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-line textarea is not available yet.

It has been requested on https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/2010